# Will 3rd party USB-Ethernet adapters work with my Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

The Nintendo Wii console has an accessory that is sold by Nintendo as a USB to Ethernet adapter, for the Wii.  The description of the item indicates it is for the Wii itself.

I've realized these accessories are typically more expensive than a standard USB to Ethernet adapter.  My question.  Does the accessory itself have to "work specifically with Wii" for it to work on the Wii, or would just buying an ordinary USB to Ethernet adapter work as well? Some of the product descriptions have something along the lines of "USB Ethernet Adapter for the Wii" and some only have "USB Ethernet adapter". If I opt for the latter, will it still work with the Wii?

Comment: This would depend on the item itself.  Some may, or may not, work with it.  I'd recommend trying it.

Comment: I think, as written, this is just too vague to be useful; You'd be better off asking about Wii and Xbox (and PS) accessories separately -  and ideally, about specific categories thereof.

Comment: @Frank Personally, I'd rather not spend money just to test things out. I'd like to see if anyone's ever tried this out already without having to test if something work

Comment: Using our precedent about [Will it work on Windows 8?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/how-should-we-handle-windows-8-compatibility-questions), this isn't the place for asking if something will work or not.

Comment: @Frank that was clearly something of a special case... Regardless, a more narrow question like "Do I need to use a Nintendo specific USB to Ethernet adapter, or will a generic one work?" (And if so, do I need to jump through any hoops and what are they) would be fine. The issue here is that the question is so broad as to be meaningless, not that it is fundamentally off topic.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Thanks, I think I'll ask it towards that. Wasn't sure if I should've made it generalized to make it useful or keep it specific

Comment: Voted to re-open, have re-edited tags and content to make question more specific

Comment: Just FYI, you do know that online play has been turned off for all Wii games, right? You would only be able to use the ethernet-to-usb for the online store and web browser.

Comment: My parents need the internet for the Amazon Prime web viewer as well as Netflix. I am well aware @Thebluefish that Internet services are gone for all games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several 3rd-party adapters that claim to support the Wii. Personally, I used to use a Rocketfish Ethernet-to-USB adapter that worked just fine on my Wii. It looks like [BestBuy has it for $7 + Shipping](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/rocketfish-lan-adapter-for-nintendo-wii/9188611.p?id=1218051663723&skuId=9188611), although I originally got mine off Ebay for ~$20.

I would avoid generic Ethernet-to-USB adapters that don't specify compatibility, although they should work on the same merit. If you find one, I would suggest Google'ing it to see if anyone has tried that particular model before.

Oherwise [a quick search on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=wii%20ethernet%20adapter&sprefix=wii+eth%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awii%20ethernet%20adapter) provides some good results for under $15.

Comment: Is there a substantial difference? To me, I am under the assumption it's just a marketing gimmick, but I have nothing to support that claim, besides the fact that typical "for Wii" accessories are much more expensive than generic counterparts.

Comment: I'm 99% sure there shouldn't be a difference, but these adapters are tested and known-working with the Wii. Considering the number of adapters in the $10-$15 range, it can't be worth trying something that you don't know works.